# How to handle constants that apply to both server and client code?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, node.js

Say you are limiting the text entered into a form to 500 characters.  You don't actually stop text entry on the live form but have a counter that alerts the user when they are over.  The JS code needs to know that the limit is 500.  Maybe the JS code trims the text on submission too.

On submit you use AJAX to do some server-side magic with the form data.  It is prudent to have the server-side PHP code now trim the comment text to 500 characters regardless of whether or not the JS code did so.

This introduces a situation where you have to enter a constant into two pieces of code, which isn't great for maintenance.  This is a simple example.  It could be much worst.

I am thinking of two scenarios here:

```
JavaScript/JQuery <-> PHP
JavaScript/JQuery <-> Node.js
```

How do you approach cleaning this up in order to reduce the maintenance burden and reduce the potential for errors?

Comment: Use only one config file for both codes? If it's a PHP file with variables, you can echo them in a JS literal, if it's a JSON file you can read it everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server is the only reliable place to store that kind of information as anything on the client-side can be manipulated.

So I would send a settings array or configuration file as a json string to the client.

Comment: So you'd have every client-side script contact the server on every time it runs to get the constants?  My concern here is that there's the potential for broken code if, for some reason, the data doesn't make it across. There's also the fact that we are adding transactions, potentially many of them, to every page.

Comment: One of my thoughts was to perhaps run a cron job that would seek out files that need these constants and modify them.  With that in place the JS would be served with the right values already stuffed into the code. This isn't very well thought out yet and it may not make sense.  I can see a lot of potential corner cases.

Comment: The other option might be to have the PHP script that generates the page (not the AJAX transaction script) run a routine that checks and updates any included JS files.  The variables in question would have to be tagged somehow so that they can be identified and the values pulled out of a common source file.  A mechanism would have to be devised to minimize server-side repeat modifications of files once they were updated one time.

Comment: @martin's You only need to send the variables once on the initial page-load. Then they will be available as long as the user stays on the same page, including in ajax requests.

Comment: I am always concerned about potential failure modes.  What do you think they might be under this scenario.  Perhaps a greater question is: How do the big boys do it?  I would imagine that with a huge code-base there are constants spread all over the place.  It has to be a maintenance nightmare without a sensible approach to managing them.